# Mousehold event in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I have this image with left and right arrow button. This image, by default is the first frame I have extracted from some gif, the original gif contains 31 frames. My goal is when the users clicks the right arrow button, I want to display the next frame and so on... Everything is working perfectly as shown below code. However, I need to add some mousehold event so that when the user click and hold the mouse, I want to keep firing the next images. How can I achieve this?

```
$('#arrow_right').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data_id = parseInt($(this).parent().find('#inner_wrap img').attr('data-id'));

    if (data_id >= 1 && data_id <= 30) {
        data_id = data_id + 1;
        var avatar_num = $('#inner_wrap').html('<img id="avatar" data-id="' + data_id + '" src="img/avatar_test' + data_id + '.gif" width="90" height="200">');
    }
});
```

Comment: How about 'taphold' event?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well you can use the `mousedown` event to start a function that displays the gif-frame: http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/ and then add another event handler for the `mouseup` event that will stop that function. That function can be called via `setInterval()` in the `mousedown`-event for example and get stopped via `clearInterval()` in the `mouseup` event.

This is an example that shows the principle:

```
var interval;
$(button).addEventListener('mousedown',function(e) {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        // here goes your code that displays your image/replaces the one that is already there
    },500); // 500ms between each frame
});
$(button).addEventListener('mouseup',function(e) {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
// Thank you, Timo002, for your contribution!
// This code will stop the interval if you move your mouse away from the button while still holding it.
$(button).addEventListener('mouseout',function(e) {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: Can you show me an example how mousedown and setInterval can work together.

Comment: What if I click and hold it and drag it then leave it, mouseup doesn't get called then

Answer (score 4):

In addition of the answer of Zim84, I should also add this piece of code!

```
$(button).addEventListener('mouseout',function(e) {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

This will take care that if someone pushes the button (`mousedown`) and holds its mouse down and leaves (`mouseout`) the button, the interval is also cleared. Without this the interval does not stop in this particularly situation.