# Running a function continuously by mouse down

Tags: jquery, mousedown

I wrote a code that shifts a slidebar and I want to improve it so while the user holds click down it keeps shifting. I wrote this code using help of different questions in this website. My problem is it falls to endless loop.

```
// The right button in the slidebar moves it to the right
var mouseStillDown = false;

function shiftToRight() {
    if (!mouseStillDown) { return; } 
    var cur = ($('#slideBar').position().left - $('#leftButton').outerWidth()) - $('.ingredient').outerWidth();
    // Checks if movement will cause the slidebar out of right edge
    if ($('#fixedPart').outerWidth() - cur > $('#slideBar').outerWidth()) {
        cur = $('#fixedPart').outerWidth() - $('#slideBar').outerWidth();
    }
    $('#slideBar').animate({ left: cur}, { duration: 500 , easing: "swing" } );
    if (mouseStillDown) { setTimeout(shiftToRight(), 500); }
};

$('#rightButton').mousedown(function() {
    mouseStillDown = true;
    shiftToRight();
}).mouseup(function() {
    clearInterval(mouseStillDown);
    mouseStillDown = false;
});
```

I also tried `setInterval(shiftToRight(), 500)` but the result was the same. it seems changing the flag in `mouseup()` is not read by the function.

Comment: What about mousemove event?

Comment: FYI [`clearInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) does not take a boolean as input

Comment: @lavrik I want this function by mouse click
@Danny I removed `clearInterval` it didn't help. How should it look like?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood initial question. [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707170/mousehold-event-in-jquery). You have problems with clearInterval parameter. It should be an interval descriptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
// The right button in the slidebar moves it to the right
function shiftToRight() {
    var cur = ($('#slideBar').position().left - $('#leftButton').outerWidth()) - $('.ingredient').outerWidth();
    // Checks if movement will cause the slidebar out of right edge
    if ($('#fixedPart').outerWidth() - cur > $('#slideBar').outerWidth()) {
        cur = $('#fixedPart').outerWidth() - $('#slideBar').outerWidth();
    }
    $('#slideBar').animate({ left: cur}, { duration: 500 , easing: "swing" } );
};

var rightIntervalId;
$('#rightButton').mousedown(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    rightIntervalId = setInterval(shiftToRight, 500);
}).mouseup(function() {
    clearInterval(rightIntervalId);
}).click(function() {
    shiftToRight();
});
```

Comment: Sorry that it took long to respond. The reason is the code made different results everytime I changed a part! and it didn't come back when I undo changes. 
First of all, this code starts working after holding the button for 500 ms. So single click is not supported. I added following click event:
 $('#rightButton').mousedown(function() {
  console.log('mouse button is down.');
     intervalId = setInterval(shiftToRight(), 500);
 }).mouseup(function() {
     clearInterval(intervalId);
 }).click(function() {
  shiftToRight();
 });

Comment: and now, when I do single click it shifts one time plus a little more. and if I hold after it shifts once, it does nothing 'till I release the button, then it shifts one more time. Surprisingly, if I undo the code, the first code stops working! I mean it works as  single click and nothing happens when I hold the button or release it. (Actually by holding the mouse button, cursor changes to text cursor and if I move the mouse it selects images! although I added appropriate CSS which prevent selecting functionality)

Comment: I added a log `'mouse button is down.'` to check the event behavior. It is called just once!

Comment: I found the bug in my code. `setInterval(shiftToRight(), 500)` I shouldn't have used () for the function.
Thanks @Danny